# Obj-C - Calling & setting values on ivars & instance methods

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, instance

I don´t understand what I might be doing wrong here since I am following an instruction book - on setting the value calling a method of an class. I have #imported it, and everything should be fine. But Xcode complains: no know class method selector for "setWeightInKilos and "setHeightInMeters". These instance methods are implemented in the "Person" class so I do not know why this happens.

```
    Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; 
    [Person setWeightInKilos:96];
    [Person setHeightInMeters:1.8];
    float bmi = [Person bodyMassIndex];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective C, there are two types of methods. Class methods, which do not act on an object, but instead usually perform some task related to that TYPE of object. For example, there are built in methods to test for network connections, device capabilities, etc. These are always denoted with a "+" sign, and cannot be called on instances of objects, only the class itself.

The other type, instance methods, are MUCH more common, and act on objects that you *instantiate* or create yourself. These are the methods that you write in the implementation file with a "-" prefix. They are things like getters, setters, or methods that you have written yourself.

In your case, you need to call these setter methods on the instance of your Person object, not the Person class itself. It doesnt make sense to set the height or weight of the entire class (nor is it possible), since every object will need to have its own unique height and weight.

You need to call:

```
Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; 
[aPerson setWeightInKilos:96];
[aPerson setHeightInMeters:1.8];
float bmi = [aPerson bodyMassIndex];
```

Answer (score 3):

These are *instance* methods, not *class* methods. Therefore you should use the name of the variable `aPerson` to invoke them on the instance, rather than the name of the class `Person`:

```
Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
[aPerson setWeightInKilos:96];
[aPerson setHeightInMeters:1.8];
float bmi = [aPerson bodyMassIndex];
```

In general, all methods declared with a `-` in front take a variable with an instance of that class; methods declared with a `+` take the class name.

There is also an alternative syntax that you can use if `heightInMeters` and `weightInKilos` are declared as properties: you can write

```
aPerson.weightInKilos = 96;
aPerson.heightInMeters = 1.8;
```

This is only a different syntax for the same thing, though; the setter methods will be invoked in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to set the instance variables called `weight` and `height`. So to fix it, do this:

```
Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; 
[aPerson setWeightInKilos:96];
[aPerson setHeightInMeters:1.8];
```

Comment: +1 Why would anyone downvote this? It's a perfectly good answer!